# Yii2 - Redirecting to external url opening in new browser tab within a controller

Tags: php, redirect, yii2

Following code will throw out Exception

> Array to string conversion

My intention is to load **external website** with special parameters in another tab. How should be coded correctly? Please notice, that redirect shouldn't render internal Controller method!!

```
$paramValue = "12";
return $this->redirect("http://example.com?param=$paramValue", ['target' => '_blank']);
```

All I achieved - without error- is to create link, but this is not the same. So, it's no alternative!

```
<center>
<?php echo Html::a(
    'StepStone laden',
    $url,
    [
        'class' => 'btn btn-success 
     btn-block',
        'target' => '_blank',
        'title' => 'Load StepStone',
        'data' => ['pjax' => '0']
    ]
);
?>
</center>
```

#### Edit(for Muhammad):

This is my solution, as it is existing actually:

```
/* It's not possible to render external URL in aonther tab using php. So, following order will render external URL in same tab:
    return $this->redirect($url); */
  
private function RenderBoerse($name, $DynamicModel) {
    $ReplaceJob = $DynamicModel->job;
    $ReplaceTown = $DynamicModel->place;
    $Jobboerse = LJobboersen::findOne(['name' => $name])->ergebnis_seite;
    $url = $this->WebStringErsetzen($Jobboerse, "###", $ReplaceJob);
    $url = $this->WebStringErsetzen($url, "&&&", $ReplaceTown);
    ?>
    <center>
        <?= Html::a("$name laden", $url, ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block', 'target' => '_blank', 'title' => "Load $name"]);
        ?></center><?php
}

 private function WebStringErsetzen($str, $suchen, $ersetzen) {
    $string = str_replace($suchen, $ersetzen, $str);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: redirect work server side  ..  so  .. http don't know how manage the client interface ..

Comment: Yes, I know about this. Maybe, it's possible to use AJAX?

Comment: is the same .. redirect don't resolve your problem

Comment: what are you trying to acheive ? do you want to redirect to an external link inside the controller action?

Comment: can you explain a bit more about the life cycle? at which point you want this new tab to open, and when you open the new tab what happens to the original tab that you had open previously, that invoked this new tab , would that previous tab be redirected to any on site `controller/action` ? if you could explain the actual scenario i might be able to help you out but it depends on if they suit your requirements or not.

Comment: the function `RenderBoerse` is it called from an action ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to redirect to an external link and post parameters along with it from inside the `controller/action` then you can do the following

```
$url='http://google.com?'.http_build_query(['param' => 12]);
return $this->redirect($url);
```

But if you want to redirect to an external link by opening a new tab then the first response you will get from anyone is **`NO`**. Above all, if the link is to be opened in a new tab then I would not say it a **`redirection`** as the current page that is invoking the new tab remains there so it would mean that the original or the previous tab is still opened and a view is loaded.

If this is correct then there is a way that you can open a link in new tab by staying inside the `controller/action`. But that does not mean that you are opening a new tab using server side, it actually will help you acomplish the data extraction and all the operations that are required to open the new link staying inside the controller and still using `javascript`.

We can use `$this->getView()->registerJs();` from within the controller to register a javscript coed that opens a new tab and as soon as the view loads it will open the new tab automatically.

see this sample action add it inside your controller and try calling it, just create a empty view file to be loaded along.

```
public function actionExternalLink() {
    $url = 'http://google.com?' . http_build_query ( [ 'param' => 12 ] );
    $script = <<<JS
            function openInNewTab(url) {
              var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
              win.focus();
            }
             openInNewTab('$url');
JS;

    $this->getView ()->registerJs ( $script , \yii\web\View::POS_READY );
    return $this->render ( 'external' );
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thought, it's not possible. Using JavaScript in controller could be solution. Reputation points for U for this code!

Comment: :) happy to hear this worked for you. I appreciate the vote up :) @tklustig

Comment: it actually register the script into view via controller not actually using javascript in the controller but this helps us out in so many ways when we do not want the code block to be the part of the view and still want to initialize or add some information in the javascript section staying in the server side code